# How to align the button below label?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I tried to put the 'search' button below the 'branch' label, here's my snippet

```html
<template>
  <base-header class="pb-4 pb-5 pt-6 pt-md-6 bg-gradient-success">
    <template>
      <div>
        <b-form inline>
          <label for="status">Status⠀⠀⠀ :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b-form-input v-model="text"></b-form-input>
          </div>
          <div class="branch">
            <div class="col-8 text-right">
              <b-form inline label-align-sm="right">
                <label for="branch">⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Branch:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <b-form-input v-model="text"></b-form-input>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <b-button variant="outline-primary">Search</b-button>
                </div>
              </b-form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </b-form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b-form inline>
          <label for="storecode">Store Code:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b-form-input v-model="text"></b-form-input>
          </div>
        </b-form>
      </div>
```

And here's the result after all [current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZwBO.png)
Thanks in advance☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening if because you're placing it inside `<b-form>` with the `inline` prop.

If you place it outside the form it should be placed below.
If you want the button to submit the form, you can target it using the `form` attribute which targets the `id` of your `<b-form>`.

```html
<b-form inline id="my-form" label-align-sm="right">
  <label for="branch">⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Branch:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b-form-input></b-form-input>
  </div>
</b-form>
<b-button type="submit" form="my-form" variant="outline-primary">Search</b-button>
```

An alternativ is to use the Bootstrap grid system, and apply the class `col-12` to the div wrapping your `<b-button>`.

```html
<b-form inline id="my-form" label-align-sm="right">
  <label for="branch">⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀Branch:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b-form-input></b-form-input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <b-button variant="outline-primary">Search</b-button>
  </div>
</b-form>
```